# Fréchet-valued symbols

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, pseudo-differential-operators

Denote by $S^m \left ( \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^n \right)$ the usual space of symbols. Now let $E$ be a Fréchet Space. We can then define $S^m \left ( \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^n; E \right)$ as the space of smooth functions $q:\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^n \to E $ which satisfy $ \sup_{z,\xi} || \partial_z^\alpha \left < \xi \right >^{|\beta|-m} \partial_\xi^\beta q ||_j < \infty$ for a family of seminorms $||\cdot||_j$ for $E$.

My question is: under which conditions can we say that $S^m \left ( \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^n; E \right)$ is isomorphic (via the natural map) to the completed projective tensor product $S^m \left ( \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^n \right) \hat \otimes E$?

I'm sure these things have been looked at before. Any suggestion on papers using them are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this follows with appropriate adjustments from the arguments for Thm.44.1 and Exr.44.6 in

> *Trèves, François*, Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels, Pure and Applied Mathematics (Academic Press) 25. New York-London: Academic Press. XVI, 565 p. (1967). [ZBL0171.10402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0171.10402).

The only condition there is that $E$ is a complete locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space and $\otimes$ stands for the completed injective tensor product. If you need to insist on the projective tensor product, you may have to invoke nuclearity.